# Personalizing wordpress menu class

Tags: php, wordpress

i'm beginning with wordpress templates, following a tutorial, I know html & css but not php :(

I want change **class="menu"** for **class="nav navbar-nav"** (because is a twitter bootstrap neccesary class) at the following code:

```
<ul id="menu-menu-principal" class="menu">
<li class="active">
<a href="http://localhost/?page_id=12">Quiénes somos</a>
</li>
</ul>
```

How can I do? In fuctions.php? How? I could change li class with the following code, but not class="menu":

```
    add_filter('nav_menu_css_class', 'my_css_attributes_filter', 100, 1);
    add_filter('nav_menu_item_id', 'my_css_attributes_filter', 100, 1);
        function my_css_attributes_filter($var) {
            if(is_array($var)){
                $varci= array_intersect($var, array('current-menu-item'));
                $cmeni = array('current-menu-item');
                $selava   = array('active');
                $selavaend = array();
                $selavaend = str_replace($cmeni, $selava, $varci);
            }
            else{
                $selavaend= '';
            }
        return $selavaend;
        }
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

With walker class 
http://wpti.ps/functions/extending-wordpress-walker-class/
http://resources.mdbitz.com/2010/08/creating-a-wordpress-custom-page-walker/

Walker renders the HTML on wp_list_pages.
It uses 5 functions:
walk, start_lvl, end_lvl, start_el and end_el.

walk, basically starts the output needed to make the unordered list and the list items inside.

start_lvl is called when the element is a child of the previous element and the output of each element starts with start_el

As you can see in the source-code of wp-includes/classes.php, 
start_lvl normally outputs the start of the unordered list and 
gives it the class 'children' and end_lvl closes the unordered list
Within those two start_el and end_el open and close the list-item 
and output all the html necessary to show the title, link to it, etc. in between.

or

walk
This function steps through the array of elements and calls the necessary start/end_lvl and start/end_el functions for each. The basic logic is as follows:
If the element is a child of the previous element it calls start_lvl.
For each element call start_el followed by end_el.
If the element is no longer a child element then it calls end_lvl.

start_lvl
    concatenates the HTML element opening tag that will contain child elements to the output.
end_lvl
    concatenates the HTML element closing tag that contains the child elements to the output.
start_el
    concatenates the HTML representation of the object minus the closing HTML tag to the output.
end_el
    concatenates the HTML closing tag element of the object. to the output.

Comment: Thank you. Reading about "walking class" that you said, I found that http://www.emanueletessore.com/bootstrap-navbar-under-wordpress/ and works fine :)